# Присоединительные союзы "а также" и "да и"

Tags: союзы, пунктуация

1) Союзы ДА И,  А ТАКЖЕ являются присоединительными союзами (об этом, в частности, говорится в учебнике «Морфология современного русского языка»). Надо ли обособлять однородные члены, присоединяемы этими союзами?

2) Относительно союза А ТАКЖЕ в правилах говорится, что не надо, что подтверждается практикой:

"Мы разделяем мнение о том, что терроризм, незаконный оборот наркотиков, оружия, а также незаконная миграция представляют собой угрозы для мира". "Эта математическая модель, а также генетические открытия убеждают нас в этом".

3) Информация по союзу ДА И как-то не очень обозначена, и на практике встречаются оба варианта:

"Во многом этот проект, да и другие перспективные проекты развития привязаны к решению о продлении международного транспортного коридора". "Этот знак, да и другие рядом с ним, я уже где-то встречал". "И не удивишься, что такое впечатление произвел он, да и другие наши монахи, на «восприимчивых» барышень".

4) Так надо или не надо обособлять однородные члены с этими союзами и почему? (С одной стороны, они однородные, с другой стороны, присоединительные.) Это должны быть одинаковые правила или разные? Также интересно, насколько эти союзы различаются по семантике, учитывая  их взаимозаменяемость?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) По  теме существует следующая  информация:

А) У ЛОПАТИНА:  При наличии между однородными членами присоединительных союзов (а также, а то и) запятая ставится:  «Она знает немецкий, а также французский язык».

Б) В учебнике для 10-11 классов сказано, что такие однородные члены не обособляются.

2) Из таких сведений можно сделать вывод, что союзы "А ТАКЖЕ, ДА И"  ПО  ГРАММАТИКЕ И ИНТОНАЦИИ не отличаются, например, от союзов А, НО, хотя их семантика особая. Следовательно, ТАКИЕ однородные члены НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯЮТСЯ, А РАЗДЕЛЯЮТСЯ ЗАПЯТЫМИ.

3) Однородные члены с союзом "ДА И" иногда ошибочно связывают  с присоединительными оборотами, не имеющими отношения к однородным членам, например:  «Имитировать речь человека, да и то на уровне простого повторения коротких слов и фраз, могут только птицы».

4) К сожалению, у меня нет авторитетных ссылок на эту тему, приходится домысливать. А считать, что автор может выбирать решение, наверное, не стоит, здесь должны быть более определенные правила.

Comment: А кто-то говорит о том, что однородные члены обособляются? Они всегда только разделяются. Зачем об этом так громко кричать? Кто-то не понимает?

Comment: Ну да, я вот не очень понимаю - не знаю, считать ли их однородными или присоединительными членами.Я не могу найти нормальных ссылок (обычно их много присылают), где бы явно говорилось, что однородные члены при наличии присоединительных союзов ведут себя как однородные члены и разделяются запятыми. В новой книге "Синтаксис современного русского языка" приведено предложение с обособлением: "Журналы, да и некоторые газеты, оказались закрытыми". Поэтому всё, что написано и выделено, - это  НЕ УТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ, а пока еще рассуждение - не знаю, правильное или нет.

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_151 - об однородных сказуемых с "да и" (соединяет слова, которые указывают на неожиданный переход от одного действия к другому; имеет другое соединительное значение; присоединяет дополнительные замечания или разъяснения к сказанному ранее. Но ясности это не добавляет. Вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: Наверное, следовало бы разрешить обе формы: разделение запятой и перечислительная интонация как базовый вариант и обособление в том случае, если однородный член с союзами А ТАКЖЕ, ДА И имеет дополняющий или уточняющий характер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я чувствую вот такое отличие. Члены предложения, присоединяемые союзом ДА И, очень похожи на вставные конструкции, а потому обособляются. То есть, когда начинаешь говорить фразу, еще не предполагаешь что-либо добавлять, это желание возникает по ходу формирования фразы. И интонация не перечислительная, а как при обособленных членах. Союз А ТАКЖЕ чаще присоединяет однородные члены, возникает интонация перечисления. Но может, аналогично союзу ДА И, присоединить вставную конструкцию. Тогда интонация другая, уже не однородные члены получаются, а такой присоединительный оборот.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я прокомментирую его в дополнении.

Answer (score 3):

Справочник "Трудные случаи пунктуации", (Д.Э. Розенталь, Былинский),  говорит: Не обособляются также однородные члены, связанные присоединительными союзами "а", "а то и", "а также" и т. п. или словами ***а следовательно, а значит*** (т. е. запятая ставится только перед союзом или перед союзом и после вводного слова и не ставится после присоединяемого однородного члена, стоящего не в конце предложения),например: ***После регистрации и обработки часть, а в некоторых случаях вся проба передается на рабочее место № 2. Бывает трудно, а то и невозможно сразу разобраться в сложной шахматной позиции. Изучение послевоенного экономического развития Албании, а также культурного роста страны позволяет сделать вывод о несомненных преимуществах социалистического строя. Химические процессы, а следовательно, и поспевание почвы совершаются равномерно.***
Исключение составляют присоединительные конструкции со значением включения, например: ***Многие города левобережья Волги, а следовательно и Казань, расположены на низком берегу (при отсутствии запятой после слова Казань получилось бы: Многие города левобережья Волги... и Казань расположены..., как будто Казань не входит в число этих городов).***

Comment: Здесь речь шла об узкой тематике: только однородные члены, только союзы (при отсутствии вводных слов). (Соответственно, включение там отсутствует). По поводу союза А ТАКЖЕ: этот союз соединяет однородные члены, но при этом выделяет среди них отдельные группы, поэтому между ними ставится запятая, о чем и говорится в правилах. А вот про союз ДА И, отнесенный к однородным членам,  информации нет. Обособление в этом случае позволяло бы выразить добавочный характер  члена, но интересно то, что союз ТАКЖЕ может заместить его в подобных конструкциях. Может быть, для А ТАКЖЕ возможны оба варианта?

Comment: София, согласен,речь об узкой тематике. Здесь информация о вводных словах - сопутствующая, акцент делается на однородные члены предложения, связанные союзами. Обратите внимание: после перечисления присоединительных союзов, идет " и т.п",т.е.список не ограничивается именно перечисленными союзами,и,на мой взгляд,союз Да И входит в эту группу, и, следовательно, механически подпадает под это правило.