# Запятая перед "да" (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "да" во фразе типа (условно): "Маша, Саша(,) да и все остальные"? Или "да" выступает в качестве усиления "и" и не обособляется?

Comment: Хороший вопрос)

Comment: Хорошо бы получить хороший ответ. Что вам подсказывает ваша чуйка?)

Comment: А-а, это вы и были с "чуйкой"!))) Она подсказывает, что не нужна запятая, хотя в Нацкорпусе больше примеров с запятой. Искал на "он да и". Вот я и не спешу с ответом, а то окажется он плохим. =)

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_151#:~:targetText=%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%20%C2%AB%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B8,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85). А вот такое, как думаете, не объясняет мою ситуацию? Я имею в виду тот пример, где запятая не ставится.

Comment: Видел это. Но тут другие примеры: сделал (то-то) да и (не) сделал (другое). То есть позиция между глаголами. С другой стороны, в плане запятой, мне кажется, ситуация может и не отличаться.

Comment: Да, там про глаголы, но там такое же усиление "да и", поэтому мне показалось, что случаи "смежные", и можно применить то же правило. Думаете, нет? Я в сомненьях. Word тоже требует запятую, но его послушать, так вообще бардак будет в тексте (контекст обычно шире границ правила; не знаю, как объяснить правильно).

Comment: *Думаете, нет?* Нет, как раз тоже думаю, что да. Написал же: *в плане запятой, мне кажется, ситуация может и не отличаться.*

Comment: Ну, вы в начале выразили сомнения, вот я и решила так) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл вразумительную формулировку с похожим, правда, примером с глаголами. Вот [здесь](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/231-znakiprepinaniyavpredlogeniyahsodnorodnymichlenami.html):

> **Запятая при однородных членах не ставится**
>   2. Если однородные члены соединяются при помощи союза ***ДА И:***
>   Например: *Возьму **да и** уйду.*

Однако ключевое слово здесь ***однородные члены*** (у вас как раз они). А это значит, что правило [отсюда](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_151#:~:targetText=%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%20%C2%AB%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B8,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85) распространяется и на наш случай.

К слову, заметил, что часто ещё встречается словосочетание *да и все мы.*

Comment: Отлично, то, что надо!)

Comment: Рад, что помог!)

Comment: @Артём Луговой Окончательный результат верен, но... Пример из этого материала у Розенталя трактуется совсем иначе: союз здесь в _присоединительной_, а не _соединительной_ функции, - в одном из сочетаний с глаголом _взять_, с которым другой глагол согласован по форме (семантически они не однородны). http://modernlib.net/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_8/ (то же у Грамоты)

Comment: @Alex_ander: спасибо, Александр! Мне тоже виделась смутно присоединительная функция, с другой стороны, для меня не было очевидно, что она исключает однородность. В общем, это не математика или у меня знаний маловато, поэтому не получается всё чётко разложить по полочкам. Сейчас поправлю. А если вы ответите и Юлия справедливо ваш ответ примет вместо моего, то, наверно, будет ещё правильнее (принимать то один, то другой ответ не очень хорошо вообще, но я не обижусь — в данном случае так и надо будет). Или удалить его совсем? Как считаете? А то, смотрю, его весь переписывать надо.

Comment: @Юлия: и простите, Юлия, что неправильно ответил.

Comment: АртёмЛуговой и @Alex_ander, спасибо вам большое за то, что нашли время на поиск информации или использование уже имеющейся в голове. Моих знаний недостаточно, чтобы хотя бы вспомнить, как такое называется и как его искать в интернете. Если вы, Alex_ander, ответите на мой вопрос отдельным ответом, я с удовольствием приму его, так как вы, похоже, поняли его лучше и глубже, чем я сама. Пока что я по четвёртому кругу читаю ваши ответы, чтобы понять что к чему.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Не считаю, что принимать то один, то другой ответ неправильно, т.к. в конечном счёте важен итог, т.е. правильно обоснованный  ответ. Сначала вы лишь выразили согласие с моей мыслью в комментариях к моему вопросу, я приняла ответ другого ответившего, позже вы написали свой и мне он показался более аргументированным, сейчас картина изменилась, хотя до конца всё же ещё не ясна. Я не хотела никого обидеть своими метаниями, не знала, что это принимается так близко к сердцу. В следующий раз, пожалуй, не стану торопиться со своим согласием на ответ.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой И вы мне всё же очень помогли вчера, поэтому извинения излишни :) В итоге-то результат верный, хоть и в причинах ещё разбираемся. Моя невежественная дремучесть была удовлетворена.

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, нет.

"Слово *да* может быть усилительной частицей, и тогда оно не отделяется знаками, поскольку сливается со следующей частью предложения".

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=335

Comment: Это не усилительная частица в данном случае, а союз.

Comment: Здесь нужно рассматривать нужно союз **да и**. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_151 https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38122/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Всё равно не ставится.

Comment: @sergzach А вот это далеко не очевидно. Из материала "Грамоты" наш случай не следует, а в пользу обратного (запятая нужна в примере с _однородными_ сущностями) есть в частности такой материал: http://uroki-russkogo-yazyka.ru/predlozhenie-s-odnim-glavnym-chlenom/nepolnoe-predlozhenie/soyuzy-pri-odnorodnyh-chlenah-i-znaki-prepinaniya-pered-soyuzami.html

Comment: @Alex_ander "Он работает быстро, да и хорошо.", "Он работает быстро, и хорошо." - в обоих случаях запятая нужна, потому что "хорошо" - не относится к "Он", а к другому подлежащему. Проблема, думаю, в отсутствии систематического руководства по русскому языку, откуда можно было бы выяснить любое правило. И, возможно, правила эти могут ещё измениться. Все, Маша, Саша да и остальные - если заменить "да и" на "и", то запятая станет не нужна. Значит, "да и" выражает то же отношение между перечисляемыми объектами, что и просто "и".

Comment: @sergzach В случае с "и" запятая не нужна (соединительное значение союза, в отличие от _присоединительного_ в первом случае). Подлежащее в обоих случаях одно. Различие смыслов в том, что в варианте с "да и" вторая часть говорится "вдогонку", как дополнительный аргумент положительной оценки труда, - это присоединительная конструкция.

Comment: Тем не менее, в своём ответе вы не так уж и далеки от истины, если обратиться к Розенталю: в нашем контексте дело в _усилительной_ функции союза **да и**, а не в соединительной при перечислении однородных членов. 
http://modernlib.net/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_8/ 
За неделю подбородок да и щёки Балахонова покрылись густой, колючей, как проволока, щетиной (Лапт.) (_да и — усилительный союз при однородных членах_).

Comment: @Alex_ander Спасибо. Но как это в обоих случаях подлежащее одно? Он работает, а хорошо-то нам. Если бы хорошо относилось к нему, то запятая была бы не нужна. "Он работает быстро и хорошо" - один смысл, "Он работает быстро, и хорошо" - несколько другой. Как и в "казнить нельзя помиловать".

Comment: Он работает быстро, да и хорошо [работает]. Смысл тот же, но вторая часть добавлена по размышлении - в таком присоединении и заключена типичная функция союза _да и_. https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/predlojeniya-soyuzami-96822.html (см. § 3134)

Comment: @ Alex_ander, посмотрела вашу ссылку http://uroki-russkogo-yazyka.ru/predlozhenie-s-odnim-glavnym-chlenom/nepolnoe-predlozhenie/soyuzy-pri-odnorodnyh-chlenah-i-znaki-prepinaniya-pered-soyuzami.html И вот что заметила: Примечание. От соединительного союза да надо отличать присоединительный союз да и, перед которым при произношении бывает пауза, а на письме ставится запятая или тире, например:

Он работает быстро, да и хорошо.
Смотритель постоял, постоял — да и ушёл.
Источник: «Учебник русского языка» С. Г. Бархударов и С. Е. Крючков, 1972

Comment: @Alex_ander Про "Он работает быстро, да и хорошо" вы тут обсудили, а как быть со вторым примером: "Смотритель постоял, постоял — да и ушёл"? Если в первом у вас возник спор по поводу того, к чему относится "хорошо", то тут же всё очевидно. Почему в примере со строителем запятая нужна, а в моём нет? Я понимаю, что для вас всё очевидно, но я что-то никак не вижу разницу. Точнее тут стоит тире, но в правиле написано, что ставится запятая или тире. Объясните, пожалуйста, если вам нетрудно.