# "А частично" — обособление

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Написал такую фразу:

*Я корицу на тёрке потёр частично, а частично в руках перетёр(,) и в кашу добавил.*

Почитал в очередной раз [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38122/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8) вопрос, но всё равно не очень понимаю, нужна ли запятая в моём случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

Розенталь:
После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого противительным или подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой предложения, запятая не ставится (т. е. последний однородный член не обособляется):
*Не род, **а ум** поставлю в воеводы.

Каждый вечер солнце садилось в море, **а не в тучи** и было при этом клюквенного цвета.

Они получили небольшую, **но удобную** квартиру.

Поставлена трудная, **зато интересная** задача.

Слышалась жалобная, **если не униженная** просьба пощадить его самолюбие.

В кинофильме рассказывается о первой, **пусть неразделённой** любви.

Получены важные, **хотя и не итоговые** сведения.

У девочки опасная, **потому что заразная** болезнь.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100

Союз А не очень кстати, потому что необходимо противопоставление (контраст), а наблюдаем повтор (слова *частично*):
*Чуть-чуть побегаю, а чуть-чуть попрыгаю.

Немного поиграю, а немного поработаю.*
Лучше союз И.

*Частично оплачу коммунальные услуги и куплю молоко.* || Молоко тоже частично куплю? Нет. К чему наречие относится — определяется по смыслу, логически.

Раз здесь имеет место следствие и фрагменты разные по размеру — неплохо было бы использовать интонационное тире, пауза там кстати. И никто и не подумает, что частично мог добавить в кашу. Предложение так и останется простым.

Comment: Мне очень нравится ответ!

Comment: А тогда не нравился?))))

Comment: Не-а, совсем не нравился, видимо, плохо прочитал)

Comment: Ну ты даёшь))) А я ж то знаю, в чём было дело. Тогда у вопроса вообще не было лайков.

Comment: Ну это могло повлиять, не то чтобы в этом дело было.)) Когда нету их, с худшим настроением читаешь ответы, ну и конечно, это может повлиять на их восприятие и желание поощрить, принять.

Answer (score 2):

А как Вы объясните запятую? Как присоединение? Но ведь здесь не "да и", а просто "И". Как авторскую можно, конечно, поставить, но это будет именно авторская запятая, а не по правилам. По правилам это однородные члены: (частично) потёр, (а частично) перетёр и добавил. Союз не повторяется - запятой нет.

Comment: Просто без запятой боюсь, как бы не поняли так, что в кашу добавил тоже частично. То есть что частично общий член.

Comment: Объяснить можно как однородные члены, а между ними присоединение: Я корицу на тёрке потёр частично, да и частично в руках перетёр, и в кашу добавил. Точнее всего скобки: Я корицу на тёрке потёр частично (а частично в руках перетёр) и в кашу добавил.

Comment: Нет, не надо мне скобок, смысл искажается.