# Пунктуация в стихотворении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, запятые, поэзия

Я прошу у вас помощи. Написала стих, очень нужна помощь в пунктуации. Поправьте, где неверно. Буду очень благодарна за вашу помощь!

> Стоит девчонка у причала,
> Глядит на синий горизонт.
> Тут скоро солнце зажжёт воду,
> Грустить ей вовсе не резон.
> Там вдалеке идёт  корабль
> И слышен чаек перезвон.
> Девчонка та не унималась взглядом,
> В руке сжимая медальон.
> Там фотография родного
> Душе и сердцу моряка.
> Они не виделись пол года,
> Он тоже рад наверняка.
> И вот настал момент их встречи,
> Все ожиданья позади.
> Разлука длилась будто вечность
> И сердце вздрогнуло в груди.
> Неповторимая улыбка,
> Родной и нежный его взгляд.
> Он приложил ладошку к лону,
> В душе волнения бурлят.
> Ответ последовал мгновенно:
> Зашевелился карапуз.
> Минуты эти так бесценны,
> Благословил Господь союз.
>
> Я обращаюсь, люди, к вам:
> Цените, ждите и любите,
> Оберегайте и храните
> Свою семью, опору в жизни,
> Гордитесь ею, дорожите.
> Великий дар — найти родную душу
> Средь незнакомцев и чужих по духу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит девчонка у причала,
Глядит на синий горизонт —
Тут скоро солнце зажжёт воду. [[красиво!](https://kartinkin.net/75245-krasivye-kartinki-zakata.html)]
Грустить ей вовсе не резон.
Там вдалеке идёт корабль, [можно и так: Там, вдалеке, идет корабль.]
И слышен чаек перезвон.

Девчонка та не унималась взглядом,
В руке сжимая медальон, —
Там фотография родного
Душе и сердцу моряка.
Они не виделись полгода — [[полгода](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)]
Он тоже рад наверняка.

И вот настал момент их встречи —
Все ожиданья позади!
Разлука длилась будто вечность,
И сердце вздрогнуло в груди:
Неповторимая улыбка,
Родной и нежный его взгляд.

Он приложил ладошку к лону —
В душе волнения бурлят.
Ответ последовал мгновенно:
Зашевелился карапуз.
Минуты эти так бесценны —
Благословил Господь союз!

Я обращаюсь, люди, к вам:
Цените, ждите и любите,
Оберегайте и храните
Свою семью — опору в жизни,
Гордитесь ею, дорожите.
Великий дар — найти родную душу
Средь незнакомцев и чужих по духу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138731/discussion-on-answer-by------2).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да, но людей обязательно надо отблагодарить, если они помогли, затрачивая своё время бесплатно. Они-то не поймут, в чём загвоздка.

Comment: @oleedd: да я и так благодарю. Но и вопросы хорошие (или хоть чем-то интересные) стоит оценивать.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Хорошесть и интересность — вещи субъективные. Не нужно наказывать за эту субъективность.

Comment: А Римма не любит ставить галочки. Предлагаю делать так: говорить, что в ответе не устраивает, почему он не решает проблему, что нужно добавить, исправить. Если ответ не полезен, предлагаю делать то же. То есть не отмалчиваться.

Comment: Я обычно как раз не отмалчиваюсь. И никого я не наказываю.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Было дело, даже со мной.

Comment: @oleedd: ну правильно, я тебя вообще не очень жаловал.))) Так что "даже" тут выглядит забавно.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Так я не про давнее время, а за последний год. У "даже" здесь не этот смысл. Оно применяется, когда говорят о себе, это не значит, что так не должно было быть.

Comment: @oleedd: нет, смысл у "даже" всегда один!) А что за последний год?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Последние 12 месяцев ориентировочно. Пусть смысл и один, но ситуации разные! Употребляют, когда говорят о себе, не имел в виду, что со смой так не должно было быть!

Comment: @oleedd: а что с последним годом-то? Ты так и не объяснил.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Тот вопрос был задан где-то в это время. Меня обидело отсутствие реакции.

Comment: @oleedd: какой тот? Про запятую?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Там что-то было про вилки или ложки. Не про пунктуацию.

Comment: Ой рассмешил!))) Не помню такого! Поиском тоже не нашлось. Найдёшь? Интересно очень. =)

Comment: Нашёл, [вот он](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466933). Оказалось, что про тёрку. Хотя да, и про запятую.

Comment: Надо было сказать, чем ответ не устраивает...

Answer (score 1):

*Полгода* пишется слитно. После *вечности* запятая — ССП. *Опора в жизни* ведь пояснение к *семье,* верно? А с запятой получается будто бы перечисление. Если это действительно пояснение, я бы выделил с двух сторон тире, но не уверен, что именно так правильно.

А в целом вроде всё хорошо. Не разбираюсь в поэзии, но мне нравится. :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138730/discussion-on-answer-by------2).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Если бы род был разным, то при запятой согласовалось бы с последним. Иначе нужно второе тире. И это легко доказать: *Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, который [не "которое"]...*

Comment: @oleedd  Да всё там хорошо с грамматикой и пунктуацией, второе тире не нужно. Пример с аквалангом здесь не доказательство, у него другая структура. Изменим род:  *Храните
свою семью – оплот в жизни, гордитесь ею.* Замена на "им" необязательна, и даже будет коряво.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Вот так делать нежелательно. Надо ссылаться на последнее, потому что тире на него переключает. Вы же не скажете так: *Храните свою семью – оплот в жизни, которой надо гордиться.*

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: я спросил, откуда ты знаешь, сколько я голосую? Я, кстати, часто голосую и за вопросы, на которые не отвечаю или за которыми не слежу потом.

Comment: @oleedd  Вы опять меняете предложение так, что структура становится другой. "Нежелательно", "надо ссылаться на последнее" – оставайтесь при своём мнении. Мне больше добавить нечего.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Просто тире переключает с общего на конкретное у Розенталя, и оно выходит на первый план, от него продолжается повествование — это норма. А вы любите свободу. А мне нужна безупречность.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой А смысл голосовать за вопросы, на которые настолько всё равно, что даже не следишь?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: ответите мне?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец В плане стилистики местоимением желательно ссылаться на последнее, а то переключили внимание на другое существительное, а потом возвращаетесь. Но это не критично.

Comment: @oleedd: нет, не всё равно, просто часто он понравится, а потом про него не вспоминаешь или просто на сайт не заходишь.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Для этого есть кнопка "Отслеживать".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Откуда знаю? Ну ведь статистика отображается. Конечно, всё относительно времени нахождения на сайте. Извини, я понимаю, что моё замечание может быть воспринято несправедливым. Просто, как мне кажется, не очень любят здесь голосовать (Alex_ander, например, тоже). У каждого свои критерии оценок, ладно, больше к старичкам не буду обращаться по этому поводу.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Чем умнее человек, тем сложнее его поразить ответом.

Comment: @oleedd  Зачем поражаться? Просто быть солидарным, поддерживающим, бескорыстным.

Comment: Да нет, мне приятно это обсуждать. Отображается общее количество голосов, ты это имел в виду? Я вот заработал "спортивное поведение" год назад. Хотя, честно сказать, иногда голосовал и ради значка, но обязательно мне ответ должен был нравиться. Просто так направо-налево не раздавал. Но тоже бывает разное настроение на щедрость. Ты, вижу, очень щедрый, молодец! Просто не очень понимаю, почему за мой неплохой вопрос часто долго не голосуют. Я вот, когда вижу хороший вопрос от старожилов, могу не вникнуть и не проголосовать, но отвечаю, обязательно вникнув, и тогда вроде обычно его поощряю.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: и ещё меня расстроило, что никто из старичков не ответил про "девочку для битья". Я понимаю, что это, скорее всего не со зла, так что никаких претензий. У тебя нету мыслей, что сказать про это? :) Про "грабушки" тоже ни одного ответа, но, видимо, никто не знает.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Сделай конкурс. "Девочка для битья" — разве что с иронией, всерьёз так сказать нельзя, потому что девочек не бьют.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой За неплохой вопрос не голосуют по тем же причинам – не видят сразу интереса, не задумываются о голосовании вообще... У меня, кстати, тоже такое было – не ставил, потому что вопрос казался неинтересным для меня. А потом ловлю себя на том, что, оказывается, слежу за всеми баталиями вокруг него,  и понимаю: не было бы вопроса, не было бы и моего внимания и маленьких открытий, вот тогда и ставлю.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: Хорошо поговорили, спасибо! Сейчас приятно. А то бывает, что напишешь что-то, а собеседник ничего не отвечает. И пусть я не задаю там каких-то вопросов, но почему-то жду, что другой как-то да прокомментирует. Но нет, обсуждение затухает. А Alex_ander жив вообще?..

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: можешь ещё всё-таки пояснить, есть какая-то ещё статистика кроме общего количества голосов у участника?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вот тебе за девочку!  За ответ Shi я давно проголосовал. Сам думаю, что ничего предосудительного в замене мальчика на девочку нет, и это, конечно, ирония, выражение, которое в литературе и живой речи раньше не употреблялось, скорее даже не приходило в голову.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: спасибо большое за мнение, хочется с ним согласиться!) И за голос! Про статистику вот жду...)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Подробной статистики вроде нет. Можно зайти на страницу участника и посмотреть, как он принимает ответы (а если нет стрелочек, то и по ним тоже можно судить о благодарности). FlossyU, например, несколько раз делали замечания на этот счёт: довольно давний участник, куча вопросов с отличными ответами и примерно 10 % реакции от нее. Но в последнее время она исправилась.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: ну да, ну да, Саш, спасибо! Вот что касается принятия ответов, то бывают такие ситуации: сложно выбрать, ни один ответ не устраивает, ответов хороших просто нету или есть интересный ответ от новичка, которому плюсуешь, но ждёшь ответов ещё и от сторожилов, чтобы они подтвердили, опровергли мысли новичка и что-то, возможно, добавили. Бывает, что кто-то хорошо ответит, но меня так разочаровывает то, что оказывается правильным, что настроения принимать такой ответ нету. Конечно, плюсик надо тогда поставить за старания, но принимать не хочется явно неприятное.

Comment: А принимаешь в следующих случаях: явно нравится чей-то ответ из многих или кто-то из стареньких даёт развёрнутый ответ и больше никаких вопросов не остаётся. Но и тогда надо быть осторожным: меня Sharon критиковала за то, что я быстро принимал ответ и этим отбивал у других желание отвечать — ведь принятый ответ уже есть, автор вроде как "закрыл" его. Вот кто-то Алину минусовал, кстати. :((

Comment: Не только её...